# How to interpret "evicted_keys" from Redis Info

Tags: redis, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elasticache

We are using ElastiCache for Redis, and are confused by its `Evictions` metric.

I'm curious what the unit is on the `evicted_keys` metric from Redis Info? The ElastiCache docs say it is a count: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheMetrics.Redis.html but for our application we have observed the "Evictions" metric (which is derived from `evicted_keys`) fluctuates up and down, indicating it's not a count. I would expect a count to never decrease, since we cannot "un-evict" a key. I'm wondering if `evicted_keys` is actually a rate (eg, evictions/sec), which would explain why it can fluctuate.

Thanks you in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 2):

From [`INFO` command](http://evicted_keys:%20Number%20of%20evicted%20keys%20due%20to%20maxmemory%20limit):

> `evicted_keys`: Number of evicted keys due to `maxmemory` limit

To learn more about evictions see [Using Redis as an LRU cache - Eviction policies](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache#eviction-policies)

This counter is zero when the server starts, and it is only reset if you issue the  [`CONFIG RESETSTAT` command](https://redis.io/commands/config-resetstat). However, on ElastiCache, this command is not available.

That said, ElastiCache derives the metric from this value, by calculating the difference between data-points.

```
Redis evicted_keys      0    5    12     18     22    ....
CloudWatch Evictions    0    5     7      6      4    ....
```

This is the usual pattern in CloudWatch metrics. This allows you to use SUM if you want the cumulative value, but also to detect rate changes or spikes easily.

Think for example you want to alarm if evictions are more than 10,000 over one minute period. If ElastiCache stores the cumulative value from Redis straight as a metric, this would be hard to accomplish.

Also, by committing the metric only as evicted keys for the period, you are protected of the data distortion of a server-reset or a value overflow. While the Redis `INFO` value would go back to zero, on ElastiCache you still get the value for the period and you can still do running sum over any period.

Comment: Thanks, that is super helpful! Am I correct in assuming that CloudWatch samples once per minute, so the "Evictions" metric from CloudWatch is really evictions/min? I see some metrics here are "per minute", I assume Evictions are as well? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/CacheMetrics.Redis.html

Comment: Yeah, in steady-state you get one data-point each minute, but it is not guaranteed. 
Redis is single-threaded. Say you are running a long Lua script, or there is some mass-eviction going on, or simply the server may busy attending a load spike, you may get data-points distanced by more or less than a minute. So don't take that per-minute too accurately.

Comment: Amazing, that is super helpful. Thank you so much!!